# Share Kit Twitter doesn't work on Iphone

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit in my iOS app.  I only use Facebook and Twitter.
Here is an example of how I do it:

```
-(IBAction)shareTwitter:(id)sender
{
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm using Clothing Assistant and I'm very happy! Buy this app!:)"]];
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"tweet!"];
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
}
```

and same metod for Facebook. Facebook works correctly in the simulator and both (iPhone and iPad) devices, but Twitter is working only on the iPad, and in the iPhone when I call shareTwitter method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the new built in Twitter in iOS 5.  It is so **easy**.  Even simpler than shareKit.